# How to show md-error in material select box in angular 2?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular2-forms

I am using reactive forms for validation in my angular 2 project. I want to highlight the fields that are invalid when 'submit' is pressed. I have achieved this in input tag by using md-Error but i am not able to do it in md-Select. Can anybody help?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPkqQ.png

This is an example of md-select that i am using:

```
<md-select placeholder="Listing Type" formControlName='listingType' required >
              <md-option *ngFor="let type of listType" [value]="type">
                {{ type }}
              </md-option>
            </md-select>
```

This is the md-input that i am using:

```
<md-input-container class="more-width">
              <input mdInput formControlName='price' required placeholder="Price">
              <md-error>Please Enter Price</md-error>
            </md-input-container>
```

This is the Validation that i am applying

```
 this.listingForm = this.fb.group({
      propertyType: ['', Validators.required]
})
```

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: updated the post with code samples

Comment: [**See this plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LsvwDQeZOfNTljC5yjyq).

Comment: this works fine in the plunker but when i use it in VS Code, no default value is selected

Comment: Hi! Did You solve this problem?

Comment: No. Currently we do not have this functionality in material. Apparently md-error is available inside md-input-container which does not support md-select right now. It is expected to be solved in the next release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has now been resolved. You just need to place the `mat-error` outside the `mat-select` and inside the `mat-form-field`. Here is an example

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite animal</mat-label>
   <mat-select [formControl]="animalControl" required>
    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [value]="animal">
      {{animal.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="animalControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an 
      animal</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

For detail you can check the following link
[Error Messages in Angular form fields](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages)

Comment: Please read about [answer]. While the contents of this link might actually solve the problem, link-only answers are discouraged on this site. Links tend to break and then the answer loses its value. It is better to include the essential parts of the link as text in the answer itself and provide the link as a reference. Your plain-text answer looks like: `PLease check the following link. Angular Material Select Box` which doesn't provide much information. If you think the link alone can help, post it as a comment (if you have 50 rep) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the red line below the  box, but no error messages as of right now. I think it's a feature that will come soon. [Issue on Github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5500)

Answer (score 0):

you can find a good example of this validating an email address in the angular material documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown).